# Print right-justified list of binary numbers

Tags: python-3.x

Here is the code to convert a decimal number `number` to binary (`DectoBin`), and to print a list of all binary numbers from `1` to `number` (`print_formatted`) :

```py
def DectoBin(number):
    j=1
    binary = 0
    while (number != 0):
        reminder = number % 2
        number= int(number / 2)
        binary= binary + reminder * j
        j *= 10
    return(binary)

def print_formatted(number):
    for j in range(1, number + 1):
        bin1 = DectoBin(j)        
        print(bin1, end='\n')
```

Output I get :

```
1
10
11
100
101
110
111
1111
```

Output I want (right-justified list of binary numbers) :

```
   1
  10
  11
 100
 101
 110
 111
1000
```

Comment: What is the pattern? Why are there sometimes 2/3/4 digits grouped?

Answer (score 0):

Define `print_formatted` function as following. This ensures that the binary numbers are correctly right justified with **the right number of spaces** before each number :

```py
import math

def print_formatted(number):
    max_bits = math.ceil(math.log2(number + 1))
    for j in range(1, number + 1):
        bin1 = str(DectoBin(j)).rjust(max_bits)
        print(bin1, end='\n')
```

`max_bits` is the number of bits used to represent `number`, and [`rjust`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) is used to right justify the string in a string of length `max_bits`.

Answer (score 0):

See [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) which introduces *Literal String Interpolation*. You can use it to right justify your print out:

```
def DectoBin(number):
    j=1
    binary = 0
    while (number != 0):
        reminder = number % 2
        number= int(number / 2)
        binary= binary + reminder * j
        j *= 10
    return(binary)


for i in range(16):
    print (f'{DectoBin(i):>5}')
```

which produces the following output:

```
    0
    1
   10
   11
  100
  101
  110
  111
 1000
 1001
 1010
 1011
 1100
 1101
 1110
```